# Removing control characters from log file in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I added bold, underline and colours to my shell script output. I used tput to do the same. Terminal output was perfect. But when i tried to add the same output to a log file, I am getting some control characters in the file as below,

> ^[[1m^[[4m^[[32mValidation^[[m^[[m^[(B
>   ^[[1m^[[4mLog file for US:^[[m^[[m^[(B

I tried sed to remove them but was unable to do so. Please help me on this.

Comment: Not adding control codes when the output is not to a terminal is generally a good practice. That being said removing those should be fine just realize `^[` is not two characters but the single character `Escape` (written as `\e` in some places, byte value 0x1b).

Answer (score -1):

You may try this (in abc file there is the string):

```
sed -re 's/\^\[(\[|\()([0-9]*m|B)//g' abc
```

Output:

```
Validation Log file for US:
```

Comment: Does not work because this still print that terminal character